# Python 3.8.5 docker alpine - CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, django, docker, gcc, celery

I'm running Django and Postgres with Docker. Just tried to add Celery to the project and I can't make it run.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
    # psycopg2 dependencies
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    # Pillow dependencies
    && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
    # CFFI dependencies
    && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
    && apk add --no-cache openssl-dev libffi-dev

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.postgres

  django: &django
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.6

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: celeryworker
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - postgres
    ports: []
    command: celery -A pyrty worker -l INFO

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: celerybeat
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - postgres
    ports: []
    command: celery -A pyrty beat -l INFO
```

Errors:

```
celerybeat_1    | [2020-08-16 17:12:54,206: WARNING/MainProcess] raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
celerybeat_1    | [2020-08-16 17:12:54,206: WARNING/MainProcess] cffi
celerybeat_1    | [2020-08-16 17:12:54,206: WARNING/MainProcess] .
celerybeat_1    | [2020-08-16 17:12:54,206: WARNING/MainProcess] VerificationError
celerybeat_1    | [2020-08-16 17:12:54,206: WARNING/MainProcess] :
celerybeat_1    | [2020-08-16 17:12:54,206: WARNING/MainProcess] CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django==3.1
psycopg2==2.8.3
djangorestframework==3.11.0
Celery==4.4.7
rabbitmq==0.2.0
Pillow==7.1.2
django-extensions==2.2.9
```

I did run `docker-compose build` and everything seemed to be ok, but then when I did `docker-compose run` I got that.

Both Celery worker and beat are throwing the same error. Let me know if the entire trace is needed.

Comment: I have shared that frustration too, could you try please adding `libc-dev`  in your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @Macintosh_89 I tried by adding `&& apk add libc-dev` in my Dockerfile and the error is the same. :(